# Required field validation jquery showing error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, requiredfieldvalidator

I validated some fields in my form.. But i have some issues..If without enter fields it shows error message.. If fill out the field still error message is showing..

How to put that ?

**My code**

```
 $("#Name").focus();
$("#Name").blur(function(){
    var name=$('#Name').val();
    if(name.length == 0){
        $('#Name').after('<div class="red">Name is Required</div>');
    }
    else {
    return true;
    }
});

   $("#Address").blur(function(){
    var address=$('#Address').val();
    if(address.length == 0){
        $('#Address').after('<div class="red">Address is Required</div>');
        return false;
    }
    else {
    return true;
    }
});
```

can anyone help me please?????

Comment: What kind of message error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove this labels after that user input some data

```
$("#Name").focus();
$("#Name").blur(function(){
    var name=$('#Name').val();
    if(name.length == 0){
        $('#Name').after('<div class="red">Name is Required</div>');
    }
    else {
        $('#Name').next(".red").remove(); // *** this line have been added ***
        return true;
    }
});

   $("#Address").blur(function(){
    var address=$('#Address').val();
    if(address.length == 0){
        $('#Address').after('<div class="red">Address is Required</div>');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('#Address').next(".red").remove(); // *** this line have been added ***
        return true;
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/B6AN7/1/)

Comment: This code has a bug. It is repeating alert every time it blur without removing previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code (I just changed the structure and added return false) :

```
$("#Name").focus()

$("#Name, #Address").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        $(this).after('<div class="red">This field is required</div>');
    } else {
        $(this).next('.red').remove()
    }
});
```

But I think the best way is to add the [required attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) to your fields like this :

```
<input type="text" name="name" required />
<input type="text" name="address" required />
```

Comment: Your code may not work correctly with `$(this).next().remove()` , this may cause the field `address` to be removed

Comment: Yes but I updated my code. I put `$(this).next('.red').remove()`

Answer (score 3):

Your code has bug that it places div as many as time as you blur in empty textbox.
This bug is also removed by my code See-:

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/XqXNT/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").focus();
    $("#Name").blur(function () {
        var name = $('#Name').val();
        if (name.length == 0) {
            $('#Name').next('div.red').remove();
            $('#Name').after('<div class="red">Name is Required</div>');
        } else {
            $(this).next('div.red').remove();
            return true;
        }
    });

    $("#Address").blur(function () {
        var address = $('#Address').val();
        if (address.length == 0) {
            $('#Address').next('div.red').remove();
            $('#Address').after('<div class="red">Address is Required</div>');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#Address').next('div.red').remove();
            return true;
        }
    });

});
```

It's better if you use required attribute which does the same work with less code and better manner.

**HTML5**

```
<input type="text" name="name" required />
<input type="text" name="address" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  to remove the added html in `else` condition.

```
 if(name.length == 0){
        $('#Name').after('<div class="red">Name is Required</div>');
    }
    else {
    $('.red').empty(); //here
    return true;
    }
```

And  the same for   `$("#Address")`